# Select a specific Row in SFrame

Tags: python, graphlab, sframe

I've been baffled on how to select a specific row within a SFrame array.  I'm able to select the first row here:

```
sf
+-------------------------------+
|               X1              |
+-------------------------------+
| [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ... |
[100 rows x 1 columns]

sf[:1]
+-------------------------------+
|               X1              |
+-------------------------------+
| [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ... |
[1 rows x 1 columns]

sf[:2]
+-------------------------------+
|               X1              |
+-------------------------------+
| [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ... |
| [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ... |
[2 rows x 1 columns]

type(sf[:1])
graphlab.data_structures.sframe.SFrame
```

Here I tried to get just row 2

```
sf[:,2]
# TypeError: Invalid key type: must be str, bytes or type
```

How could I select any row in the dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select a row with:

```
import graphlab as gl
sf = gl.SFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,9,1]})
# select first row
print sf[0]
# select second row
print sf[1] 
# and so on
# convert first row to an SFrame
sf_one_raw = sf[0:1]
# convert second row to an SFrame
sf_one_raw = sf[1:2]
```

Comment: the problem is type(sf[0]) is a dict vs an SFrame

Comment: You didn't say you wanted a SFrame. Post edited for returning a one row SFrame.